# Magento 2 : Admin Create Order and Custom Option Type

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, custom-options

I have created new product custom option type and everything is working well except when creating an order from admin. When product has native product options such as file, configure link permit to define product options. But when it has my custom option type, configure link does not work.

I may have forgotten a declaration somewhere, but do not manage to find where.

Thank you for your help,